# How do you specify the duplex preference of a PDF using dompdf?

Tags: php, pdf, dompdf

The PDF spec allows specifying the duplex preference of a PDF. From the 1.7 specification:

> Duplex (name) (Optional; PDF 1.7): The paper handling option to use when printing the file from the print dialog. The following values are valid
>
> - Simplex: Print single-sided
> - DuplexFlipShortEdge: Duplex and flip on the short edge of the sheet
> - DuplexFlipLongEdge: Duplex and flip on the long edge of the sheet

Does Dompdf support setting this preference in the rendered PDF?

Comment: This is hardware/driver related, not software (document).

Comment: I am trying to ask if there is a SOFTWARE configuration option that is possible to set to enable the desired functionality. It may not be possible, but surely people should be allowed to confirm if it isn't possible.

Comment: Duplex printing a pdf is a software tickbox, and it is potentially possible to set an instruction for a word document when that is dynamically generated.

Comment: This actually is not a hardware/driver question. The PDF spec allows specifying duplex preference for the PDF. Whether or not this setting is honored is an implementation question, but the question still holds.

Comment: The answer is no with the current release (0.8.4) per https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf/issues/2046